# Add focus on each new text input which is added

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im using this script i found to add a textbox when a user clicks on a text link, Is there any way i can make it so each new text box that appears automatically has the cursor inside the text box.

Heres the script:

```
function add(orderType) {

//Create an input type dynamically.
var element = document.createElement("input");
//Assign different attributes to the element.
element.setAttribute("type", "text");
element.setAttribute("name", orderType + "[]");


var foo = document.getElementById(orderType);

//Append the element in page (in span).
//Create the option text
var a = document.createTextNode("Choice: ");
foo.appendChild(a);
foo.appendChild(element);
var br = document.createElement("br");
foo.appendChild(br);
i++;    
}
```

Many Thanks

Comment: `element.focus()` at the end after `foo.appendChild`

Comment: @megawac - Nice one! worked perfectly. Sorry stackoverflow automatically added jquery, i wasn't sure 100% what it was.

Answer (score 2):

Call `element.focus()` after you append it to `foo`:

```
function add(orderType) {
    //Create an input type dynamically.
    var element = document.createElement("input");
    //Assign different attributes to the element.
    element.setAttribute("type", "text");
    element.setAttribute("name", orderType + "[]");


    var foo = document.getElementById(orderType);

    //Append the element in page (in span).
    //Create the option text
    var a = document.createTextNode("Choice: ");
    foo.appendChild(a);
    foo.appendChild(element);
    var br = document.createElement("br");
    foo.appendChild(br);

    element.focus();//focus new input

    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A jQuery solution will be selecting the last input and then focus it, where #ordertype is the container id :

> $("#" + orderType + "input:last").focus();

Comment: Not quite, `orderType` is a variable id. Should be `$("#" + orderType + "input:last")`

Answer (score 0):

it has been some time since i programmed in javascript, and re-learning it now... i do believe **.focus** is what you want.

```
document.getElementById(orderType).focus
```

=====================

.tabindex ((hopefully correct syntex)) is used with the "tab" key.

```
document.getElementById(orderType).tabindex = 0     //first name
document.getElementById(orderTyppe_2).tabindex = 1  //last name
document.getElementById(orderTyppe_3.tabindex = 2  //address
document.getElementById(orderTyppe_3.tabindex = 3  //city
etc...
```

is more used for a signup page or filling out an shipping address page. were you simply setup tabindex's, so when ya press tab it takes you to the next highest tabindex number on the document. can be more usefull when pages are dyanamically changed via javascript.

==================

in back of my mind i want to say there is another

```
.something
document.getElementById(orderType).something
for <input /> or <input></input> or like elements
```

but i do not remember it right off. that deals with "cursor" but it might be a cross browser script thing. and only implemented in one of the various major browsers out there.